# How to validate data before an insert, on multiple records with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm building an interface to create multiple records in the db, using Codeigniter.

The input is text copied and pasted from an Excel file, with the fields names in the top row.

Parsing that text and converting it into an array is easy enough. But I try to think what would be the best way to validate the data before inserting it into the database (make sure all the not-null fields are filled, all the integer fields are numeric, all the foreign keys are valid, etc.).

I'm looking for something similar to the form validation rules in CI. Any pointers as to where I should start looking?

Answer (score 1):

Well! this is only some idea i am not posting any code here.
Create a library and define methods for integer , numeric and foreign keys.
if any does not contain any data fill it with default means if string then with '' and if integer then with 0 and so on. Now create methods to run validation and do some logic as how you want to display errors. i have done the same thing.